# group_concat only display's one column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database structure like so

```
 Car
 - id   
 - carname
 - image
 - category
 - status

Parts
 - partid
 - partname

CarParts
 - carpartid
 - carid(fk)
 - partid(fk)
 - amountid(fk)

Category
 - id
 - categoryname

Amount
 - amountid
 - amountvalue
```

and here is my query:

```
SELECT group_concat(parts.partname) as parts FROM car left join  carparts on car.id = carparts.carpartid 
left join  parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid
left join amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid where status = 1
group by car.id
```

but this only display parts and nothing else i want

- carname
- image
- category
- status

Comment: You are only outputting part info

Comment: how do i output everything?

Comment: Also, this is obviously wrong: `car.id = carparts.carpartid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass column names in select, see example below:

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(parts.partname) as parts,
    car.carname,
    car.image,
    car.category,
    car.status
FROM car 
    left join  carparts on car.id = carparts.carpartid 
    left join  parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid
    left join amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid where status = 1
group by car.id
```